# Where do I put a custom config (.cfg) file in AWS MWAA Airflow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

I have a config file, dev.cfg, that looks like this:

```
[S3]
bucket_name = my-bucket
```

I need this in my code to do S3 things. I do not have the access (nor will I be given it) to modify the environmental or config variables in the AWS console. My only method of putting files in S3 is the CLI (`aws s3 cp ...`).

This is the project directory structure in S3:

```
my-bucket/
  dags/
    dev.cfg
    some_dag_file.py
  plugins.zip
  requirements.txt
```

In the plugins.zip file, there is a plugin that should set the path to dev.cfg to an env var (DEV_CONFIG_PATH) that my code uses:

```py
import os

from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin

os.environ["DEV_CONFIG_PATH"] = os.path.join(
    os.getenv('AIRFLOW_HOME'), 'dags', 'dev.cfg')


class EnvVarPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = 'env_var_plugin'
```

However, I'm getting an import error in the Airflow UI:

```
configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'S3'
```

Any help is appreciated.

I'm using MWAA with Airflow version 2.4.3 running python 3.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try asking your infra team to update the config: core.lazy_load_plugins : False